# Spring Data JPA: Ошибка при выполнении запроса с условием WHERE IN

Tags: spring, spring-data

Есть две энтити:

```
public class QuestionEntity extends AbstractEntity {

    @Type(type = "text")
    private String text;

    @Builder.Default
    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "questionCategoryRelation",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "questionId") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "categoryId") }
    )
    Set<QuestionCategoryEntity> categories = new HashSet<>();

}

public class QuestionCategoryEntity extends AbstractEntity {

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, updatable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private String color;

    @Builder.Default
    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<QuestionEntity> questions = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Есть репозиторий:

```
@Repository
public interface QuestionRepository extends JpaRepository<QuestionEntity, Long> {

    @Query(value="SELECT q FROM QuestionEntity q ORDER BY function('RAND')")
    Optional<QuestionEntity> findTopRandomQuestion();

    @Query(value="SELECT q FROM QuestionEntity q WHERE q.categories IN :categories ORDER BY function('RAND')")
    List<QuestionEntity> findTopByCategoriesIn(@Param("categories") Set<QuestionCategoryEntity> categories);

}
```

Мне надо случайным образом выбрать вопрос у которого есть некие категории.

Но при выполнении получаю ошибку:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [QuestionCategoryEntity(name=Maven, color=null)] did not match expected type [java.util.Set (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [QuestionCategoryEntity(name=Maven, color=null)] did not match expected type [java.util.Set (n/a)]] with root cause java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [QuestionCategoryEntity(name=Maven, color=null)] did not match expected type [java.util.Set (n/a)]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.validate(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.setBindValue(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.expandListValuedParameters(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:636)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1536)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:135)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:129)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125)
```

Что не так?

Comment: А почему у вас нет, гетеров/сетеров и конструктора по умолчанию? мне почему-то кажется что они должны быть

Comment: или у вас там `lombok` подключен что ли?

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov да, верно

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключается в неправильной постановке запроса.
Запрос

```
SELECT q FROM QuestionEntity q WHERE q.categories IN :categories ORDER BY function('RAND')
```

предполагает, что в `:categories` будет коллекция/массив объектов `Set<QuestionCategoryEntity>`. Проще говоря, проверка будет не на наличие отдельных категорий в `:categories`, а всего сета (находится ли сет в сете).

Запрос, который должен делать то, что ты хочешь, будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
select distinct q from QuestionEntity q 
join q.categories c 
where c in :categories 
order by function('rand')
```

Обрати внимание на `distinct`, это важно, т.к. этот запрос может возвращать список с повторяющимися записями.